# I have a list of points and would like to determine if they form a circle

Tags: c#, list, math, vector, gestures

I'm using C#, I have a list of Vector points and would like to try and approximate how close they look like a circle.

Any ideas how to implement this or if someone else has?

Comment: If what you're really trying to do is recognize a gesture, this link might be helpful: http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/

Comment: Without code this is a poor question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Pick any three points from that list, find the center of their appropriate circle

We can do this, using triangle circumcircle construction method, you find the medians of all three sides (two are sufficient) and their intersection is the center of the circle. Something like this:

```
public PointF findCenter(PointF a, PointF b, PointF c)
{
    float k1 = (a.Y - b.Y) / (a.X - b.X) //Two-point slope equation
    float k2 = (a.Y - c.Y) / (a.X - c.X) //Same for the (A,C) pair
    PointF midAB = new PointF((a.X + b.X) / 2, (a.Y + b.Y) / 2) //Midpoint formula
    PointF midAC = new PointF((a.X + c.X) / 2, (a.Y + c.Y) / 2) //Same for the (A,C) pair
    k1 = -1*k1; //If two lines are perpendicular, then the product of their slopes is -1.
    k2 = -1*k2; //Same for the other slope
    float n1 = midAB.Y - k1*midAB.X; //Determining the n element
    float n2 = midAC.Y - k2*midAC.Y; //Same for (A,C) pair
    //Solve y1=y2 for y1=k1*x1 + n1 and y2=k2*x2 + n2
    float x = (n2-n1) / (k1-k2);
    float y = k1*x + n1;
    return new PointF(x,y);
}
```

2) Check if the other points are equivalently distanced from this center, if yes, you have a circle, if no, you don't.

P.S. I haven't tested the code, so be prepared to debug. Ask if you need anything else

Comment: Picking *any* three points will work only if your points form a perfect circle. If you are looking for an approximate one, e.g. in a situation where an end-user draws a circle with his finger on a touchscreen, you might get a completely wrong center.

Comment: As @dasblinkenlight pointed out, my answer is a mathematical approach. Given that computational algebra is discrete, this isn't applicable if you copy-paste the entire code without modification. You should add an error function that allows +/- 2px (or other value) coordinate oscilations. You compute the error by: `(Math.Abs(targetPoint.X - returnedPoint.X) + Math.Abs(targetPoint.Y - returnedPoint.Y)) < 2`

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility:

1. Find the centroid
   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_finite_set_of_points) of
   the points
2. Determine the distance (radius) of each point from the location of
   the centroid
3. Calculate the distribution and determine if the points
   are within acceptable tolerances (e.g. standard deviation < ±0.05 × mean radius or something like that)

Without knowing more about the source of the points, it's hard to suggest the best solution.

These might be of use: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02276879#page-1 and http://www.dtcenter.org/met/users/docs/write_ups/circle_fit.pdf. Those methods will give you the best fitting circle through the points, but you are still going to need to determine whether your data points are close enough for your purposes.

UPDATE: based on the 'gesture' tag, somebody has already implemented it: http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/

Comment: Just to highlight (as in my comment in VaclavSir's answer) that you cannot use the "gesture approach" blindly, but only under very specific conditions (= a gesture actually occurring). From the OP's question, it is not clear the source of the data points (the tag "gesture" is included; but it might be just a way to attract answerers of close-enough fields) and this kind of approaches cannot be used with random points.

Comment: @varocarbas Yes, it would be nice if the original poster would chime in and provide a few more details.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the "gestures" tag I guess you not only want to know how close are these points to the smallest-circle (search for "Smallest-circle problem"), but you have to be concerned also about their order and spread:

[image]

1. I would start with the distance from the smallest-circle. If they are too far, you're done, it's not a circle.
2. If they are close enough to your configured threshold, compute the angle between the vector defined by the circle center, first point and each other point (picture bellow)
3. Check that each angle is greater than the previous.
4. Check that difference between any two angles next to each other is not over some configured threshold.
5. Check that the last point is close enough to the first one.
6. You will probably think of some other checks eventually, so make it simple to extend.

[image]

Comment: Why do you assume that the points are provided in certain order? Also bear in mind that you cannot start analysing angles, as far as any geometrical figure can be generated from equivalent angles. First thing to be analysed is the defining feature of a circle (i.e., all the points at the same distance from the center); the angles can only come into picture at a later stage to determine if it is a whole a circle or a portion of it.

Comment: For checking the last point close enough to the first, I'd suggest that the sum of angles to that point > 340 degrees or similar. Assuming it's a gesture you just want a minimum of a full circle and probably don't care if you exceed it (e.g. 1.5 rotations). @varocarbas the order of points is important if the source of points is a gesture on a touch screen

Comment: @ColinYoung Please, take a look at my answer (CLARIFICATION 2). The order of the points (if any) is EXTREMELY important. I asked VaclavSir why he assumed that there is an order. If an order exists (you are drawing the circle manually), this fact has certainly to be taken care of; if there are a bunch of random points, you cannot bring this issue into account because would drive to wrong results. The OP didn't mention this issue and that's why I don't think that VaclavSir should have taken it into account (or he should have mentioned that his approach cannot be used with random points).

Comment: I assume there is an order, because the question is tagged "gestures". I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Take any three points from your point set. 
If the points are `co-linear` then, your point set doesn't all lie on a circle. 
Find the [circumcircle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Triangles) of the triangle. The diameter is given by: `d = (a*b*c)/2*area`. The center of the circle is the point of intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of the three sides.

Now for every remaining point in the point set, if the distance from the center is not equal to the radius then the points are not on a circle. You can speed up the calculations by comparing the square of the radius against the square of the distance between the given point and the center.

Comment: I see my reply doesn't answer your question. But maybe you're looking for a [`circle of best fit`](http://www.cs.bsu.edu/homepages/kerryj/kjones/circles.pdf), which can provide you a statistical estimate on how close the points are to forming a circle. You can then set bounds (in terms of standard deviation), for a point set to qualify as forming a cirlce.