# How to determine if a set of co-planar points form a circle in 3D?

Tags: python, geometry

I have a set of co-planar points in 3D. Some of these points that are co-planar form a circle while some co-planar points do not.

Is there a way for me to program (ideally python) and determine what points are forming a circle and what points do not?

I have seen solutions for this problem in 2D space [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801728/i-have-a-list-of-points-and-would-like-to-determine-if-they-form-a-circle) which probably won't work in 3D while the solutions proposed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16209/how-to-determine-the-center-and-radius-of-a-circle-given-some-points-in-3d) are "mathematica" focused that I am unable to apprehend fully.

Can someone please guide me towards the possible solution?

Comment: If the points are really coplanar, reduce the problem to 2D through a rotation and translation of your coordinate system.

Comment: Alternatively, find the center of a circle circumscribed around three of the points, and check if the others are sufficiently close to being one radius away from said center.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a go and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any three points *always* lie on a circle. Find one circle, then test any other points. Doing that in 3D is almost the same as in 2D (https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/489058-how-to-draw-a-circle-given-three-points-in-3d-space/)